# Assign user roles with CanCan?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

Ive setup a application with two basic user roles.

A admin who can manage everything and a normal user and can create things (jobs & clients) but can not delete.

I'm a bit stumped though as to how  can assign roles to the users. I assume it would be a case of adding a role column to my database? As user's are only created by the admin user. I need to add some sort of collection select to my form?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: I tried the **One role per user** instructions as detailed on the cancan wiki [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) but i'm recieving the error `uninitialized constant User::ROLES`

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer :)

I inserted this code..

```
  ROLES = %w[admin user]

    def role_symbols
      [role.to_sym]
    end
```

Into my `User` model and put `<%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>` into my form :)